# Activiti-rest - Create a deployment by model id

Tags: activiti

Can I create a deployment from model id by activiti-rest? (deploy an existing model)

- I have created a model by [rest-api](http://activiti.org/userguide/index.html#_create_a_model) and [updated editor-source](http://activiti.org/userguide/index.html#_set_the_editor_source_for_a_model) for this model by api too. Then I want to create a deployment of this model by api, can i do it? (if create deployment by activiti-explorer, we can do it by simple click "deploy" on model action of model, but I want to do the same thing by activit-rest)

Thanks.

Comment: There is no such api yet. but you can create your own rest api which takes model id as parameter and deploys the same.

Comment: I have tried `repositoryService.createDeployment()`, but it seem not support to deploy from model id, do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can deploy a bpmn process or bar/zip archive from the Rest API using the following call:

http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#_create_a_new_deployment

A typical request to create a deployment with a file called "atmox.bar" would look like:

POST http://localhost:8080/brazos-open/service/repository/deployments

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="atmox.bar"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

Hope this helps.
Greg

Comment: Hi Greg, but I already have an existed model on activiti server, I want to deploy this model, not by the way upload zip or bar file. are there any api like POST http://localhost:8080/brazos-open/service/repository/deployments with the body {modelId: 1}.

Comment: Hi Quan, there is no existing REST API to deploy a process that was modeled in Activiti Explorer and deploy it to the runtime server. It is a relatively easy piece of work to extend the REST API and add this capability, but it isnt available out of the box.

Comment: Hi Grep, I have tried to create my api, but `repositoryService.createDeployment()` seem not support my expectation (deploy by model Id), do you have any suggestions? thanks so much.

Comment: You will find all the answers you need in the deployModelerModel() method of the EditorProcessDefinitionDetailPanel.java file in the "activiti-explorer" module.

Comment: I have create my api follow step the save with `deployModelerModel()`, But I got an error "`Failed to instantiate standard serializer (of type com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.NullSerializer): Class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BasicSerializerFactory can not access a member of class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.NullSerializer with modifiers \"private\"`, although the deployment is successful.